# Return new something in function returning a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, constructor, return, shared-ptr, implicit-conversion

I have a function that returns a shared_ptr to a const object. Returning a shared_ptr constructed from a pointer returned by operator new works, but returning that pointer directly causes compilation error :

```
Error   3   error C2664: 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty>::shared_ptr(std::nullptr_t)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'script::float_data *' to 'std::nullptr_t'    c:\xxx\value.cpp    59
```

Here is the code causing the error :

```
shared_ptr< const data > float_data::operator + ( shared_ptr< const data > rhs ) const
{
    int rhs_as_int; float rhs_as_float;

    switch( rhs->to_numeric( rhs_as_int, rhs_as_float ) )
    {
    case E_INT:
        return new float_data( val + rhs_as_int );
    case E_FLOAT:
        return new float_data( val + rhs_as_float );
    }
}
```

And the classes are :

```
class data
{
public:

    enum type
    {
        E_INT,
        E_FLOAT,
        E_STRING
    };

public:

    virtual ~data() { }

public:

    virtual std::shared_ptr< const data > operator + ( std::shared_ptr< const data > rhs ) const = 0;

    virtual std::shared_ptr< const data > operator - ( std::shared_ptr< const data > rhs ) const = 0;

    virtual std::shared_ptr< const data > operator * ( std::shared_ptr< const data > rhs ) const = 0;

    virtual std::shared_ptr< const data > operator / ( std::shared_ptr< const data > rhs ) const = 0;

    virtual std::shared_ptr< data > operator = ( std::shared_ptr< const data > rhs ) = 0;

public:

    virtual type to_numeric( int & as_int, float & as_float ) const = 0;
};

class int_data : public data
{
private:

    int val;

public:

    int_data( int i );

public:

    virtual std::shared_ptr< const data > operator + ( std::shared_ptr< const data > rhs ) const;

    virtual std::shared_ptr< const data > operator - ( std::shared_ptr< const data > rhs ) const;

    virtual std::shared_ptr< const data > operator * ( std::shared_ptr< const data > rhs ) const;

    virtual std::shared_ptr< const data > operator / ( std::shared_ptr< const data > rhs ) const;

    virtual std::shared_ptr< data > operator = ( std::shared_ptr< const data > rhs );

public:

    virtual type to_numeric( int & as_int, float & as_float ) const;
};

class float_data : public data
{
private:

    float val;

public:

    float_data( float f );

public:

    virtual std::shared_ptr< const data > operator + ( std::shared_ptr< const data > rhs ) const;

    virtual std::shared_ptr< const data > operator - ( std::shared_ptr< const data > rhs ) const;

    virtual std::shared_ptr< const data > operator * ( std::shared_ptr< const data > rhs ) const;

    virtual std::shared_ptr< const data > operator / ( std::shared_ptr< const data > rhs ) const;

    virtual std::shared_ptr< data > operator = ( std::shared_ptr< const data > rhs );

public:

    virtual type to_numeric( int & as_int, float & as_float ) const;
};

class string_data : public data
{
private:

    std::string val;

public:

    string_data( const char * s );

public:

    virtual std::shared_ptr< const data > operator + ( std::shared_ptr< const data > rhs ) const;

    virtual std::shared_ptr< const data > operator - ( std::shared_ptr< const data > rhs ) const;

    virtual std::shared_ptr< const data > operator * ( std::shared_ptr< const data > rhs ) const;

    virtual std::shared_ptr< const data > operator / ( std::shared_ptr< const data > rhs ) const;

    virtual std::shared_ptr< data > operator = ( std::shared_ptr< const data > rhs );

public:

    virtual type to_numeric( int & as_int, float & as_float ) const;
};
```

I don't think this is something specific to C++11, but i'm new to C++11 so i'm not sure. I don't understand why not both ways to return the pointer works and why the compiler automatically chooses the constructor expecting a nullptr_t.

Comment: use `std::make_shared`.

Comment: You should really learn to pare away all the irrelevant code. See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15bcac7cbd09b0d2 for a minimal example.

Comment: I chose to leave the class definitions in case it mattered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because [the constructor of `std::shared_ptr` is explicit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr), and therefore in the return statement the compiler cannot convert the raw pointer to a `std::shared_ptr` implicitly when trying to construct the returned object. You *must* return a `std::shared_ptr` instead.

You are seeing the strange error because the compiler tries to match the raw pointer parameter to the non-explicit constructor ([number 5 here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr))

```
constexpr shared_ptr( std::nullptr_t );
```

Although g++/clang++ are much more helpful in diagnosing the issue, example error:

> error: could not convert from 'int*' to 'std::shared_ptr'

Comment: Okay thanks for your answer. Is there a performance overhead when creating a temporary shared_ptr and returning it ?

Comment: No overhead, there's RVO, an exception to the as-if-rule. Which on further consideration might be sufficient for this all on its own, though with deeper analysis.

Comment: @Virus721 no, not at all, all (decent) compilers perform what's called [return value optimization (RVO)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization).